# Can't Update Angular Module After Minification?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I manually bootstrap my application, because I need to get a configuration from an external source first.

I overwrite a config module that exposes a constant, so that the application and bootstrapping can use it.  it falls back the already-declared one if there is a problem with the http call for the config.

This works fine until I minify/concatenate/uglify the code.

Any ideas why?

code:

```
$http.get('app-config.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                //this will overwrite the existing default app.config module and the appConfigConstants object
                angular.module('app.config', []).constant('appConfigConstants', response.data);
                deferred.resolve();
            })
            .catch(function (errorResponse) {

                if (console) {
                    console.warn('Unable to fetch application configuration- using default', errorResponse.status);
                }
            });
```

Comment: `angular.module('app.config', [])` should still exist even after minification, you can take a look at it what's it now.

Comment: Show the rest of your file. It sounds like you aren't using string dependency injection which will cause problems if you minify it.https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05. See 'a note about minification'